# Is it a good idea to order a ticket for the London Eye in advance?

Tags: sightseeing, tickets, london

On the [official site](http://www.londoneye.com/TicketsAndPrices/Tickets/Default.aspx) of London Eye, you can buy online tickets that are 10% cheaper than tickets book directly at the location.

If I buy a standard ticket, do I have to specify a date or even a time when I want to visit it? Or can I order a time range? There is also the possibility to buy a fast track ticket. It is almost 9 GPD more expensive than a standard ticket. Are the queues really that long that it would justify such a a huge amount of money?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If I buy a standard ticket, do I have to specify a date or even a time
>   when I want to visit it?

Yes you have to specify both date and one of the 30 minutes time slots. You have to stick to the time slot you booked, you'd better not be late. Buy it online to get the discount.

> Standard ticket or fast track?

Standard ticket by all means. In 2010, during the festive period of Christmas/New Year's Eve the queue was only 20 people long when I took the ride. It is not worth buying the fast track, even if it is pouring down or whatever. The "London Eye View 360º" on its own costs *1 GBP*, you can buy it separately (it's included in the fast track price).

*Source: own experience*

Comment: Whenever I go around the London Eye (usually on Saturday afternoon,  I must confess), the queue is much bigger than 20 persons but not big enough to make it worth £9 from my point of view but you're the only one to really know how much your wasted time is worth.

Comment: Contrary-wise, on our trip last year (around Easter) we went back to upgrade to FastTrack because the standard line was multiple-hours long (vs. 10-15 minutes on the FastTrack). Absolutely worth it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on when you go.  When I've walked past on weekends I've been SHOCKED at the length of the queues.  But other times it's been less - it'll depend on tourist traffic, times of year, the weather, other events and so on.

I've been on it twice, once in the day, once at night, both times didn't require more than a 10 min wait.  My relatives also went on almost immediately during a winter's weekday.

It is cheaper online, but I can't say for sure what the restrictions are on that.  Just one suggestion - IF you do want to do Madame Tussauds and the London Dungeon, they're all owned by the same company and you can usually get a discount for doing 2 or more of them.  I haven't done the wax museum, but I can't recommend London Dungeon - I thought it was a bit of a rip off really.

The London Eye though - is totally worth it - day or night!